# How to use angular-ui-bootstrap (modals) in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'd like to edit some data from a table using a modal. There are various interfaces in the typescript definitions for angular-ui-bootstrap from definitelyTyped, however they are undocumented and I'm not able to find any examples on how to use them.

- IModalScope
- IModalService
- IModalServiceInstance
- IModalSettings
- IModalStackService

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts#L146

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

[image: layout]

Am I right to assume that both ItemsListController and ItemDetailModalController need an instance of the same scope in order to exchange the data? And how can I define the controller and the template for the modal directive using the interfaces above?

I already found this non-typescript example here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

However, as a beginner I've got a hard time understanding what's going on if samples throw everything in one single file without separating the concerns.

Answer (score 22):

The instance injected by angular will be of type `ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService`.

And since you are using "controller as" syntax, there is no need to start using `$scope` here, instead you can use resolve as shown in the [angular-ui modal example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Here's the example code:

```
class ItemsListController {
    static controllerId = 'ItemsListController';
    static $inject = ['$modal'];

    data = [
        { value1: 'Item1Value1', value2: 'Item1Value2' },
        { value1: 'Item2Value1', value2: 'Item2Value2' }
    ];

    constructor(private $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) { }

    edit(item) {
        var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: ItemDetailController.controllerId + ' as modal',
            resolve: {
                item: () => item // <- this will pass the same instance 
                                 // of the item displayed in the table to the modal
            }
        };

        this.$modal.open(options).result
            .then(updatedItem => this.save(updatedItem));
            //.then(_ => this.save(item)); // <- this works the same way as the line above
    }

    save(item) {
        console.log('saving', item);
    }
}

class ItemDetailController {
    static controllerId = 'ItemDetailController';
    static $inject = ['$modalInstance', 'item'];

    constructor(private $modalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance, public item) { }

    save() {
        this.$modalInstance.close(this.item); // passing this item back 
                                              // is not necessary since it 
                                              // is the same instance of the 
                                              // item sent to the modal
    }

    cancel() {
        this.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Juanjo, I like this style that you are using and I prefer it. However, I have some problems. I have posted my question in a separate post in here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103868/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-and-typescript

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right to assume that both ItemsListController and ItemDetailModalController need an instance of the same scope in order to exchange the data?

Yes. I actually think of modals as an extension of `ItemsListController` containing members `shownDetails:ItemDetailModalController`. Which means you don't need to come up with a messy way of sharing `$scope` as its just a single `$scope`.

> And how can I define the controller and the template for the modal directive using the interfaces above?

This is what I have (note that you are sharing the scope):

```
            this.$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'path/To/ItemModalDetails.html',
                scope: this.$scope,
            })
```

Where `$modal:IModalService` corresponds to what angular strap gives you : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: So does the controller actually configures/calls the modal? Isn't this breaking SOC?

Comment: No. Its the same as doing `error = "bad thing happened"` from the controller. Controller drives the UI, just doesn't use `$element`

Comment: Yes, I was really confused the first time I saw $element, though it seems very common in examples. I just thought there was a way to configure the modal on the HTML side. Well, guess everythings clear now (except for the DT interfaces)

Comment: I am using a *really* old version (1.5 years old). The interfaces correspond to the new version of angular strap and I've updated the answer to reflect that. AKA The DT interfaces are correct.